# How to nest required apostrophe in onclick with double quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have an onclick function like this

```
onclick= "js.popup('js.name', 'db.name', 'text')"
```

In this context db stands for database,js.name, and text are just text that comes back. Db.name is a variable that's determined on what comes back.

The problem is that occasionally a db.name result with an apostrophe is pulled from the database and the function throws an error. The function is supposed to launch and open up a specific item for that user. It works with every user, but throws an error for names with apostrophes.

Comment: Why no write the call like this instead: `onclick= 'js.popup("js.name", "db.name", "text")'` then you will not have any problems whit db.name has apostrophe or not.

Comment: Does not work. Still throws error

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: onclick= 'js.popup("js.name", "bob 'O Bill ", "text")'  That cuts off everything after the apostrophe.

Comment: Yes I know, but what does the error message say?

Comment: You're not telling us how you generate that HTML. I suppose you're using some server side language such as PHP? Use `addslashes` for each arg then `htmlspecialschars` to properly encode the whole attribute.

Answer (score 0):

So I have made some research and came up with this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">

</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var js = {

  checkString: function(s) {
    if (s.indexOf("'") > -1) {
        s = s.replace(/'/g , "&#39"); //HTML escapes code for apostrophe
    }

    return s;
  },

  appendHTML: function(s) {
    var cleanString = js.checkString(s);
    $("#wrapper").append("<div onclick = 'js.popup(\"" + cleanString + "\")'>Click Me</div>");
  },


  popup: function (message) {
    alert(message);
  }
}

js.appendHTML("stringWith'Apostrophe");
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t59htpuL/1)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. `js.appendHTML()` is sending a string to the first function, and then that function will pass on that string. All is working fine, check the fiddle.

Comment: I don't understand how that would fix this issue. If you have a div with onclick= "js.popup('js.name', 'db.name', 'text')" It needs to open up an image so it needs to tolerate any " ' " inside of the db.name result.

Comment: Could you show me in the context of the questions actual text?

Comment: You need to clean the db.name from ' and use a HTML escape for that character. When you have done that then you can add you onclick-event to the div. In my example I am adding a div with onclick-function to the div #wrapper. Hope that you understand, because the information on how you put the parameters to the onclick-function is not clear.